# how to get date difference in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

My Schema is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
```

I am  trying to get difference between two date .

No clue.

Answer (score 3):

Example to get date difference is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <xsl:param name="currentDate" select="current-date()"/>
  <xsl:param name="yesterdayDate" select="'2013-05-12'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentDate - xs:date($yesterdayDate)"/><!-- Result in duration  -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```